# Given collection of sets how to turn it to collection of disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a finite collection of sets $A_1$,...,$A_n$. Is there an algorithm which gives a new collection $B_1$,...,$B_m$, which consist of pairwise disjoint sets, $\cup B_i=\cup A_j$ and each $B_i$ is a subset of some $A_j$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write $B_k=A_k\setminus\bigcup_{j<k}A_j$. It might be the case that several of the sets will end up as being empty. Remove those.

Comment: I have been trying to show that the union of the Bs you have written is equal to the union of the As rigorously, but have struggled. Does anyone know where I can find a link to this proof?